# Kendo DataSource Request serialize and deserialize is not working

Tags: c#, kendo-asp.net-mvc

To send kendo datasource request to webapi, I have serilized the kendo dataSourcerequest to string to apply filter and sorting operations in webapi. But when deseralizing the string to dataSourcerequest i am getting error as "token expected"

**Controller :**

```
public ActionResult GetGridData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
      //converting object to string
      string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
}
```

**Web api:**

```
public ActionResult GetGridData(string request)
   {
        //converting string into object
        string jsonStr = JsonConvert.DeSerializeObject<DataSourceRequest>(request);
        //Here error is throwing as "Expected Token"
    }
```

**DataSourceRequest:**
`{ Page : 1, PageSize : 10, Sorts : [], filters : { [{ "value":"Accident Response Fee Laws","operator":"eq","field":"subTopic"}],"logic":"or"}  }`

Comment: Can you post the contents of the request string and the structure of your DataSourceRequest.

Comment: @Thangadurai Please check the updated answer

Comment: post your DataSourceRequest class also.

Comment: Your JSON content looks invalid. There is an extra } at the end.

Comment: That was just copy paste error, DataSourceRequet is kendo class

Comment: All the key must be enclosed within " in the JSON. It should be "Page":1 not Page:1. Probably you need to check the place where you are serializing the object.

Answer (score 1):

Currently Telerik does not support serialising the DataSourceRequest. This class implements interfaces inside of the class, preventing the class from being serialised.

The best way I can think of handling this is to create a custom class that will convert the DataSourceRequest to a custom serialisabe class. This would also require you to include a function to convert the custom class back to the DataSourceRequest Telerik class.

There is a current request for this feature. 
Please vote here to try and get Telerik to implement this functionality:
http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/127393-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/17207828-serialization-support-of-datasourcerequest-and-app

Answer (score 0):

Just pass over the data as a query string

in your angular

```
const queryStr = `${toDataSourceRequestString(gridState)}`;
 return this._http
      .post(`${url}?${queryStr}`)
```

in your webapi

```
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using System.Web.Http.ModelBinding;
public ActionResult GetGridData([ModelBinder(typeof(WebApiDataSourceRequestModelBinder))] DataSourceRequest request)
   {
   }
```